# How to create client side fixtures for cucumber velocity for Meteor?

Tags: meteor, cucumber, meteor-velocity

In the examples on the cucumber for velocity website, one is shown how to create fixture code, but the code seems to run on the server.
How do you create client side fixture code?
I would like to replace the Date object with a stub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a debugOnly package that has a client file that contains a meteor method, then call the method client side only using `client.execute()`. Saying that, you can just do the work the fixture would do (stub the date) inside the

```
client.execute(function() {
  Date = {
    now: function() {return 'someDate'}
  };
});
```